# Search two functions $f$ and $g$: $g(x,y,z,w)\leq\max(|x-y|,|z-w|)\leq f(x,y,z,w)$.

Tags: functions, inequality

Let us consider $\max$ function
$$\max(x,y)=x \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{if}\ \ \ x>y$$
$$\max(x,y)=y \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{if}\ \ \ x<y$$
and $x,y,z,w\in \mathbb R$. I'm looking for two bounds (upper and lower) to $\max(|x-y|,|z-w|)$, i.e., two functions $f$ and $g$ such that:
$$g(x,y,z,w)\leq\max(|x-y|,|z-w|)\leq f(x,y,z,w)$$

For the upper bound I thought:
$$\max(|x-y|,|z-w|)\leq \max(|x|+|y|,|z|+|w|)\leq|x|+|y|+|z|+|w|$$
therefore
$$f(x,y,z,w)=|x|+|y|+|z|+|w|$$

I would appreciate some help for lower bound.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Note that this $f$ is not actually linear in $x,y,z,w$. Did you mean "linear in $|x|,|y|,|z|,|w|$"?

Comment: Excuse me, it was a mistake. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the lower bound you can consider (if you are not forcing $g$ to be positive)
$$
\max(|x-y|,|z-w|)\geq \max(|x|-|y|,|z|-|w|)\geq \frac{|x|-|y|+|z|-|w|}{2}=g(x,y,z,w),
$$
since the mean of two numbers is always less than or equal to the maximum of them (actually, the maximum equals the mean only when the numbers are the same).